# Jquery Django Add fields (or hide and show) with the value of a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

So i am programming in Django and i want that with the value of a Choice field a new field appear.
so i have this in my template in Html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $( document ).ready(function() {
  if( $('#{{clinic_details.parity}}' == 'AtleastOne' ) ){
    $('#paritefield').show();
  }else{
  $('#paritefield').hide();
  }
 });

 </script>
         <div class="form-group">
           <div id="require"> 
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ clinic_details.as_p}}
           {{ ClinicForm.}}
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div id="paritefield">

          {{ parityfield.as_p }} 

         </div>
         </div>
```

And in forms.py i have

```
class ClinicForm(forms.Form):
    SELECT_ETHNICITY = (('1','Europe and North Africa'),('2','East-Asian'),)
    origin = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, 
    choices=SELECT_ETHNICITY, label ="Origin")
    SELECT_DIABETE = (('1','None'),('2','Not documented'),)
    diabete = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, 
    choices=SELECT_DIABETE, label ="Diabetes")
    SELECT_PARITY = (('None','None'),('AtleastOne','At least One'),)
    parity = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, 
    choices=SELECT_PARITY, label ="Parity")
    fields = ['origin', 'diabete',]

class ParityfieldForm(forms.Form):
    SELECT_PARITYFIELD = (('1','None'),('2','Not documented'),)
    parityfield= forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=SELECT_DIABETE, label ="Parity field")
```

and finally in view.py i have

```
def form_view(request):
    clinic_details = ClinicForm(request.POST or None)
    parityfield = ParityfieldForm(request.POST or None)
    title="Form"
    if clinic_details.is_valid():
       fsv = clinic_details.save(commit=False)
    return render(request,"template.html",{"clinic_details":clinic_details, "parityfield":parityfield, "title": title})
```

So I want that when the value of the Choice field parity is 'AtleastOne' it shows another field but without refreshing the page, Thanks to Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need Jquery for that?
You can try to check the value when rendering the page and if it is equal to `AtleastOne` you can add the field.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="require"> 
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ clinic_details.as_p}}
    </div>
</div>
{% if clinic_details.parity == 'AtleastOne' %}
   <div class="form-group">
       <div id="paritefield">
         {{ parityfield.as_p }} 
       </div>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But it doesn't seems to work. If i want the result of a ChoiceField i just need to do form.field not form.field.value or other things right ?